# Installing Django 1.11.2 with pip install. Pip.exe trying to install SONAR.AM.C.J!g9 virus?

Tags: python, django

I have set up a virtual environment for my first Django project, and have tried to install Django using

```
pip install Django
```

However, when I do so, Norton warns that pip.exe is trying to download the SONAR.AM.C.J!g9 virus. Based on what I've read, I don't want to take the risk of going further so am having to remove pip.exe from the environment. I've searched for similar issues but not having any luck so far.

Can anyone advise me how I should proceed?

Many thanks!

Set up is Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just disabled the Norton firewall and anti-virus temporarily. All installed without problem of course. Surprised that no other Norton users ran into this issue.